# How to integrate jquery code in extjs4

Tags: jquery, extjs4, weather

I am working in extjs.I want to find weather of specific city. i got reference from"http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/pune.json". Its giving all information related to given city in json format, by writing following code in html file-

```
   <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">

</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        $.ajax({
                                    url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Pune.json",
                                    dataType : "jsonp",
                                    success : function(parsed_json) {
                                        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
                                        var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
                                        alert("Current temperature in "
                                                + location + " is: " + temp_c);
                                    }
                                });
                    });
</script>
```

Its working correctly. Now i want  to integrate this jquery code in extjs's controller. So can someone guide me how to integrate above jquery code in extjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following extjs code does the same that yours, so you can use it inside of the controller.

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
    url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Pune.json",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var location = parsed_json['location']['city'];
        var temp_c = parsed_json['current_observation']['temperature_string'];
        alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_c);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanx a lot sir for replying. i have included above code in controller.But its giving me error as-"TypeError: Ext.data.JsonP is undefined" So what changes i need to do? Can you please guide me

Comment: You should load [Ext.data.JsonP](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP) before using it, to load the class you can use for an example [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lf6/).
Ext.require('Ext.data.JsonP', function () {
/*your code*/
});

Comment: Thanx for reply sir...its working.. I want to ask one more thing. How can i change city name dynamically. i.e. suppose i have variable storing city name. so how to change url-"http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/pune.json" so that city name will get replaced by that variable. And we will get information of cities depending upon that city name that variable has. Please guide me

Comment: var city = "Pune";
...
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
 url:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/4ab310c7d75542f3/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/" + city + ".json"
...
});

Answer (score 0):

There is no conflict between ExtJS and jQuery (both have their own namespace). You can use jQuery in your ExtJS controllers as long as jQuery is loaded before your app.js. I use jQuery with ExtJS since ExtJS 4.x and never had any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In both sencha touch and extjs all your javascript code is to be placed in your app.js file or other class js files.  You would never put code like that in a script tag in the html.  If you want to make a call to that location before your app loads or first thing you would put it in your Application launch function or put it directly above.

```
//DO YOUR AJAX CALL HERE BEFORE YOUR APPLICATION LAUNCHES

    Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function() {

            //OR INSIDE THE LAUNCH FUNCTION
        }
    });
```